# How can I add '\r\n' to a stringbuilder without the stringbuilder interpreting the output?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

In C# how can I add a `"\r\n"` string to a `StringBuilder` without the `StringBuilder` interpreting the string as containing a new line?

Here is some code as an example:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.AppendLine("].join('\r\n');");
textBoxOutput.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

The output is displayed as:

```
].join('
');
```

Rather than:

```
].join('\r\n');
```

Comment: `stringBuilder.AppendLine("].join('\\r\\n');");` just double `\`

Comment: The `StringBuilder` isn't "interpreting" anything. You'll see the exact same thing by just having `textBoxOutput.Text = "].join('\r\n');";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stringBuilder.AppendLine(@"].join('\r\n');");
```

This is a [verbatim string literal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)